# How to fix a requests exceptions ConnectionError

Tags: python, flask, deployment, python-requests

I have done preprocessing of a dataset and now I need to deploy it using Flask.
I am getting this error.

> ConnectionError(e, request=request)
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /preprocessing (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x000002D405DBC0D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it'))

How can I fix it?
Below I provide the code that generates the error

```
import os
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

base_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
data_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'dataset', 'diabetes_dataset.csv')
output_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'output')

datafile = pd.read_csv(data_dir)
column_label = 'Outcome'
cols = list(datafile.columns[:-1])
variable_name = 'Outcome'

response = requests.post(
    url= 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/preprocessing',
    json= {
        "data_dir": os.path.join(base_dir, 'dataset', 'diabetes_dataset.csv'),
        "label": column_label,
        "cols": cols,
        "variable_name": variable_name,
        "output_dir": output_dir
    }
)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Is there something that listens to the port 5000 on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

change 127.0.0.1 to to concrete ip address